# mozilla's softwares don't run anymore after trying vulkan driver on 20.04.3

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, vulkan

I've installed 'vulkan mesa drivers' for a try, and then remove it.
https://linuxconfig.org/improve-your-wine-gaming-on-linux-with-dxvk
All good but since firefox don't start any more. (same for thunderbird)
All others softs are not affected (games, etc..). Error message:

```
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
Exiting due to channel error.
```

Can someone help me to understand what's happening?
I can downgrade to firefox 75, but it can't use my profile.
Re-install up to date version don't help.
I finally installed flatpack version, and manually copy my old profile to the flat one.
But it's temporary solution and I'll like to recover normal situation.
I also need to recover Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem don't come from vulkan's driver but from oibaf PPA.
So don't use this PPA.
First of all, remove PPA:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

But it don't remove oibaf package's.
To do this,list residual packages:

```
 apt list | grep oibaf
```

Then reinstall all listed package manually via **apt install** forcing the version ("**=*version***" after package name), referring to your ubuntu version https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/allpackages:

Example for ubntu20.04 today:

```
sudo apt install libdrm-common=2.4.107-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 libdrm-intel1=2.4.107-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 libdrm2=2.4.107-8ubuntu1~20.04.2 libegl-mesa0=21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 libgbm1=21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 libgl1-mesa-dri=21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 libglapi-mesa=21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 libglx-mesa0=21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 libva-drm2=2.7.0-2 libva-wayland2=2.7.0-2 libva-x11-2=2.7.0-2 libva2=2.7.0-2
```

If some listed package don't exist in your ubuntu version, just purge it, ex:

```
sudo apt purge libllvm14*
```

Now system is back to previous state and runs normally.

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to recommended to use oibaf ppa. I assume you already used `ppa-purge oibaf` to remove it.

I also assume that you have either AMD or Intel GPU, not NVIDIA; since NVIDIA overrides most of Mesa libraries.

If you have NVIDIA, then reinstall the NV drivers; because it's possible that when you installed, Mesa drivers got placed on top of NV ones; which NV will not like.

Solutions:

## Ensure Vulkan is removed in apt

```
sudo apt remove --purge libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

None of these 4 packages should be installed.

## Install Vulkan

The following command should be enough:

```bash
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

Having Vulkan drivers is not a bad thing.
However if you don't want to have Vulkan installed, keep reading.

## Reinstall Mesa's OpenGL

```bash
sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri libglu1-mesa libglx-mesa0 xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-all
```

## Remove any left over Vulkan

After removing vulkan, the following folders & files should not exist. If they do, remove them (or back them up):

- ~/.local/share/vulkan/
- /etc/vulkan/
- /usr/share/vulkan/
- /usr/local/share/vulkan/
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.* (notice the wildcard)
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so
- /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so
- /usr/share/lintian/overrides/mesa-vulkan-drivers/

## If everything fails, debug

Analyzing the output of `LD_DEBUG=libs` may help you find the culprit by seeing suspicious libraries being loaded:

```bash
LD_DEBUG=libs firefox 2> output_to_analyze
```

For example I have Vulkan installed so mine says:

```
      8323: find library=libvulkan.so.1 [0]; searching
      8323:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
      8323:   trying file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
...
unrelated stuff
...
      8323: calling init: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1
```

Even if Vulkan isn't the culprit at all, the output from this environment variable may help you find out what is going wrong. For example it would be very suspicious if it crashes right after loading a particular librari.

If you can spin up a VM or use another computer to compare the outputs of your machine against a healthy one; it may also help you find the problem.

Additionally `glxinfo | grep string:` should give a hint that real Mesa GL drivers are being used, e.g. mine is:

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT (sienna_cichlid, LLVM 14.0.1, DRM 3.46, 5.18.11+)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.0.5 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.0.5 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 22.0.5 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

I'm using Kisak's PPA and this is output is telling me that indeed Mesa is being used and `AMD Radeon RX 6800 XT (sienna_cichlid, LLVM 14.0.1, DRM 3.46, 5.18.11+)` tells me that it is HW accelerated (if it says `llvmpipe` or `swrast` then you have a huge misconfiguration to fix)

Cheers and good luck.

Comment: $ sudo apt remove --purge libvulkan1 libvulkan-dev vulkan-utils mesa-vulkan-drivers remove all that: :/ bad for k3b and vlc!
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS : (DELETED)
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad* gwenview* k3b* kdenlive* kio-extras*
  libkf5notifyconfig5* libplacebo7* libvkd3d1* libvulkan-dev* libvulkan1*
  libwine* libwine-development* phonon4qt5* phonon4qt5-backend-vlc*
  playitslowly* vlc* vlc-plugin-video-output* vulkan-tools* vulkan-utils*
  wine64*

Comment: Mesa reinstalled, all /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so file removed and nothing better. LD_DEBUG=libs firefox 2> output_to_analyze gives nothing. ` $ glxinfo | grep string
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
(...)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but for now I still searching solution or at least understand what happen.